# Simple UIKit game: What is a good approach for repeatedly putting new objects on screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, timer

Currently, I'm building a simple game using pure UIKit. In my game content MVC, I have a CADisplayLink timer object that is activated on game and is repeatedly calling gameLogic method for displaying new objects. The method calculates and renews object positions on the screen. The frameInterval of my timers is 2 frames. Now, I need somehow to set an interval for the repeated appearance of new objects on the screen. The solution that I have used so far is to use a static counter in gameLogic method. Here is a fragment of the method:

```
-(void)gameLogic{
  static int timeCounter = 0;
  if ((timeCounter % 50)==0){ 
    [self addItemToScreen];
  }
  ...
  timeCounter++;
```

At every 50th cycle of gameLogic method execution, I'm putting a new object on screen. The rest code of gameLogic method repositions the existing objects. Currently, everything is managed by only one timer. The other solution that IMHO should work is to have a separate timer for adding new objects on screen. But I'm not sure, is it a better solution, and will they work successfully concurrently. What are your opinions about these approaches? What other solutions you propose to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its fine to have all your objects respond to a frame counter. However, I would likely instead dispatch a notification across your application instead of having one function that has a ton of code in it, doing all kinds of things. I think you really should consider breaking up all that logic into separate classes, i.e. have a GameObjectCreator class that responds to the notification posted when your timer fires, and only have that class add objects to the view. For your code that rearranges the objects on screen, they could also respond to the same notification, and be either handled by a parent controller to manipulate all the objects, or each individual object could respond to the notification as well. Performance wise I'm not sure if using notifications is bad with a lot of objects responding at once, but something like this is more the approach I would take so you don't have all this spaghetti code in one single timer function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have heard about notifications but I haven't use them yet. It sounds promising to make screen objects listen to the broadcasted notifications. In that case, do I have to register every object as observer (addObserver:selector:name:object:) to default notification center? And then in my GameLogic method, repeatedly post notifications?

Comment: It is also very interesting, how broadcasting messages are propagated between objects/observers. Are there any concurrency? For my game, it very important, that every object/observer would  receive a message and only one message within one timer loop from NSNotificationCenter. For example, if there would be 10 objects on the screen then it would be non-acceptable if any object would be slowed down or would start to move faster then others :)

Comment: A dispatched notification happens all in the same run-loop, so all objects registered with the notification center would receive the notification at essentially the same time (or at least in the same run-loop). 

And yes, you would need to have every object you want to respond to notifications register with addObserver:selector:name:object. Also make sure you do 

'[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]'

when deallocating objects that have registered with NSNotificationCenter. Otherwise you'll get memory leaks and other bad things.

Comment: And yes again, you'd have your GameLogic method repeatedly post notifications. If you want some items to update on a different interval, you can add logic to determine when to post those notifications within the same GameLogic method, or just make a new timer with its own interval to dispatch its own notification. I'd prefer the latter since it seems cleaner

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give a try. Good luck in your projects ;)